apoc.path.expand filtering nodes/links
I've got the following query which follows all relations into and out of a given node out to a particular distance (in this case 3 hops):
MATCH (r:Record {record_id: $id})
CALL apoc.path.expand(r, null, null, 0, 3) YIELD path
RETURN path, length(path) AS hops
ORDER BY hops

Now, I need to restrict this to show incoming relations only, and to filter on the type of relationship. This documentation would appear to offer the answer to that:
https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.0/overview/apoc.path/apoc.path.expand/
The difficulty here is the fields:
relationshipFilter :: STRING?, labelFilter :: STRING?
Relations between each Record are handled by a RecordAssociation with a label, though this function requires strings. Is apoc.path.expand therefore not able to handle paths where an intermediate relation is used, and, if so, what would I need instead?

Please add to your question the relevant parts of your data model. For example, it is not currently clear if RecordAssociation is a node label or a relationship type, and how it is connected to a Record.

RecordAssociation is a relationship type. I'm not sure what you mean by "how it is connected", I'm afraid.

To only traverse inbound relationships with type RecordAssociation you would write:
MATCH (r:Record {record_id: $id})
CALL apoc.path.expand(r, '<RecordAssociation', null, 0, 3)
YIELD path 
RETURN path, length(path) AS hops ORDER BY hops

There are more configuration options documented here.
If you are on 5.9+, you are probably better off using quantified path patterns, which would allow you to write the following:
MATCH path = (r:Record {record_id: $id})<-[:RecordAssociation]-{0,3}()
RETURN path, length(path) AS hops ORDER BY hops

One particular advantage of quantified path patterns is that you can also filter on the properties of relationships and nodes. This query is filtering on a property label on relationships with type RecordAssociation:
MATCH path = (r:Record {record_id: $id})<-[:RecordAssociation {label: "value"}]-{0,3} ()
RETURN path, length(path) AS hops ORDER BY hops


That looks interesting, thanks. Would this allow filtering on the parameters of the RecordAssociation? The one that interests me is its "label" field.

Yes, if I understand you correctly. I've updated my answer with an example.

Thanks. I was using an older version but upgraded to 5.20 and was able to use the last of your examples successfully - thanks!
